# Sending a chunk of HTML to another URL using postMessage()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**Objective:** Copy a chunk of HTML and send it to a website on another domain.

**My problem:** The website I'm working on and the website in the iframe are on different domains. I own both of them and have set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow the websites to communicate to each other. However, I can't seem to pass the HTML chunk to the parent window.
I've tried `parent.window.postMessage(chunk, http://www.parent-page.com)` (chunk is the chunk of HTML code) but I get this error:
`Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.`
I have also tried to use ajax to send a PUT request to the parent window but, I get a 404 error that it cannot find the parent window. *I am running the parent window from my local server.

**My Question:** Can anyone tell me the best way to send an object, containing HTML code, from an iframe to the parent window given that the two websites are NOT on the same domain?

**EDIT:** I removed the stuff about a skeleton object as that was out of the scope of the question I was really trying to ask.

Comment: You might be trying to send an object that can't be serialized. Please see 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#Things_that_don't_work_with_structured_clones

Comment: Is there a reliable way to convert it to a string?

Comment: If you own both sites couldn't you go through the parent to get to child content?

Comment: @zer00ne I tried doing that but I got a cross domain error. That will only work if both pages are on the same domain.

Comment: @CodyCook actually communication through an iframe in either direction seems to be the norm cross-site or not. Meaning if you can access a site through an iframe then the reverse is true as well, AFAIK. The exceptions are `postMessage()` because both each side must declare origin, CORS, etc. I wrote something for `postMessage()` parent to iframe cross-site. The reverse process is the almost the same, the difference being slight.

Comment: @zer00ne I've tried getting the child frame's HTML using `var viewFrame = $('iframe#frame').contents();`. I get the following:  `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63343" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ccook.oegllc.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Comment: Is your localhost XAMP, IIS, Apache?

Comment: I'm using Webstorm. localhost is created the IDE

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by `skeleton object`? I not sure what you mean by that, so I can't recommend how to serialize it.

Comment: @EL45 I've edited my question to further explain the skeleton object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I wrote to solve this. Any constructive criticism is welcome.

### Code on parent window's website:

```js
//send a message to the website in the iframe
  $("#frame").on("load", function (event) {
    var viewContainer = $('#element-highlight');
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var receiver = iframe.contentWindow;
    var location = 'http://www.child-website.com';
    event.preventDefault();
    receiver.postMessage("sendStructure",location);   
  });

//listen for a response
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { //event = onmessage event object
    if (~event.origin.indexOf('http://ccook.oegllc.com')) { //indexOf returns a -1 if the searchValue is not found    
      var structure = event.data;
    var container = document.getElementById("element-highlight");
    container.innerHTML = structure;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="../jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="frame-container">
        <iframe id="frame" src="http://www.main-site.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <div id="element-highlight">
          <!-- Store Skeleton Copies here -->
        </div>
</div>
  
</body>
```

### Code on the website that is shown in the iframe:

I can't get the case statement below to look any better.

```js
        //listen for command from main-site.com
        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { //event = onmessage event object
            if (~event.origin.indexOf('http://www.main-site.com')) { //indexOf returns a -1 if the searchValue is not found
                switch(event.data){
                    case "sendStructure":
                   var structure = getStructure(),
                      tempNode = document.createElement("div");
                      structure.appendTo(tempNode); //appends structure to html document
       var str = tempNode.innerHTML; //creates a serilized version of the structure
       parent.window.postMessage(str, event.origin); //send structure string to main-site.com
     break;
    //I reccomend using a case statement if the two sites will be sending more than one message to each other
                    default:
                        sendError();
                }
            }

        });


        function getStructure(){
            //this method creates a skeleton of the course page you are on
            //returns a skeleton object
            console.log("compiling structure");
            var viewFrame = $('body').contents(); //<-change 'body' to whatever element you want to copy
            var visible = viewFrame.find('*:not(html body)').filter(':visible');
            var overlayElements = visible.map(function (i, el) {
                    var el = $(el);
                    var overlayEl = $('<div>');

                    overlayEl.addClass('highlight').css($.extend({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        width: el.outerWidth(),
                        height: el.outerHeight(),
                        'z-index': el.css('z-index')
                    }, el.offset()));

                return overlayEl.get();
                });
          
        return overlayElements;
        }

        function sendError(){
            console.log("main-website's request could not be understood");
        }
```